# Number of roots of $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to find the number of roots of $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ in an interval $[a,b]$?
For instance, let $p=31$ and $[a,b] = [1,100]$ so the equation becomes $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965510/number-of-roots-in-range It seems the two of you are participating in the same online contest

Comment: What online contest, @HagenvonEitzen ?

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3=1\iff (x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$$

One root is clearly $\;x=1\;$ , and the others must come from the quadratic, whose discriminant is

$$\Delta=1^2-4\cdot1\cdot1=-3$$

Thus, besides one, there are other roots iff $\;-3\;$ is a square modulo $\;p\;$ . For $\;p=3\;$ we have, of course, one unique triple roots, since $\;x^3-1=(x-1)^3\;$

Comment: We need to find count of these roots and not to find if root exists or not

Comment: Yeah, well: the answer stands. You first must know when $\;-3\;$ is a square $\;\pmod p\;$, or what is the same: what's the sign of the Lagrange' symbol $\;\binom{-3}p\;$

Comment: How we are checking when is -3 a square (mod p) ?

Comment: Using Gauss lemma, Legendre's symbol....isn't this question from number theory? This should be known in order to attack this problem, I think: $$\binom{-3}p=\binom{-1}p\binom 3p$$ and etc.